# Merge multiple jQuery scripts into more efficient code

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to merge those scripts or make code more efficient? I'm new to jquery and I think I produce too much code. Is it possible to optimize it?

```
<script>
    jQuery(".myClass1").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").addClass("addedClass1");
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").removeClass("addedClass1");
       }
    );
</script>


<script>
    jQuery(".myClass1").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").addClass("addedClass2");
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").removeClass("addedClass2");
       }
    );
</script>
```

is it possible to optimize those also:

```
<script>
    jQuery(".myClass1").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").addClass("addedClass");
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass1 h3").removeClass("addedClass");
       }
    );
</script>


<script>
    jQuery(".myClass2").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass2 h3").addClass("addedClass");
        },
        function () {
            jQuery(".myClass2 h3").removeClass("addedClass");
       }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try combining your selectors, taking advantage of the `this` object, and passing a single handler function employing the `toggleClass` method  like so:

```
jQuery(".myClass1, .myClass2").hover(
    function () {
        jQuery(this).find("h3").toggleClass("addedClass");
   }
);
```

First, by combining your selectors `".myClass1, myClass2"` with a comma between them, you can chain a single `hover` event to all elements of both classes.

Second, by using the handler function's `this` object, you are able to reference the current element that fired the hover event, without having to know its specific class.

Finally, by passing a single handler function and using the `toggleClass` method you perform the same action that two handler functions served with two separate calls to `addClass` and `removeClass`.